# ¿Como abrir un modal dentro de un component (vue js)?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

Tengo un componente definido en [vuejs](/questions/tagged/vuejs).

```
Vue.component('persona-component',require('./components/personas/personaComponent.vue'));
```

Definido así:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-fluid"><!--container-fluid-->
            <h1 class="page-header">Personas</h1>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createPersona"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Nueva Persona</a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="MyTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="5">
                        <div class="form-inline" style="float: right;">
                            <input id="buscar"  v-model="texto" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba algo para filtrar" style="margin: 3px" /> 
                            <a id="btnBuscar" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" v-on:click.prevent="findPersona(texto)" style="margin: 3px"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Buscar</a>
                            <a id="btnActualizar" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" v-on:click.prevent="getPersonas()" style="margin: 3px"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i> Actualizar</a>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>DNI</th>
                        <th>Apellidos y Nombres</th>
                        <th colspan="2"><center>Acciones</center></th>
                    </tr>                    
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                     <tr v-for="persona in personas">
                         <td width="10px">{{ persona.PERS_varDNI}}</td>
                         <td>{{ persona.PERS_varApPaterno}} {{ persona.PERS_varApMaterno}}, {{ persona.PERS_varNombres}}</td>

                         <td width="10px">
                             <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" v-on:click.prevent="editPersona(persona)">Editar</a>                
                         </td>
                         <td width="10px">
                             <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" v-on:click.prevent="deletePersonas(persona.PERS_varDNI)">Eliminar</a>
                         </td>
                     </tr>    
                </tbody>                
            </table>
            <nav>
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li v-if="pagination.current_page > 1">
                        <a href="#" @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page - 1)">
                            <span>Atras</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li v-else>                        
                            <span disabled style="background-color: #dee2e6">Atras</span>                        
                    </li>

                    <li v-for="page in pagesNumber" v-bind:class="[ page == isActived ? 'active':'']">
                        <a href="#" @click.prevent="changePage(page)">
                            {{ page }}
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li v-if="pagination.current_page < pagination.last_page">
                        <a href="#" @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page + 1)">
                            <span>Siguiente</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li v-else>                        
                            <span disabled style="background-color: #dee2e6">Siguiente</span>                        
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="col-sm-5">
            <pre>
                {{ $data }}
            </pre>
        </div>-->
        @include('persona.createpersona')
        @include('persona.editPersona')
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        //
        created: function(){
            this.getPersonas();     
        },
        data:function(){
            return{
                personas:[],
                texto:'',
                pagination:{
                    'total' : 0,
                    'current_page' : 0,
                    'per_page' : 0,
                    'last_page' : 0,
                    'from' : 0,
                    'to' : 0
                },
                newPersona:{PERS_varDNI: '', PERS_varApPaterno: '', PERS_varApMaterno: '', PERS_varNombres: ''},
                fillPersona:{PERS_varDNI: '', PERS_varApPaterno: '', PERS_varApMaterno: '', PERS_varNombres: ''},
                errors:[],
                offset: 2,
            }
        },
        computed:{
            isActived: function(){ 
                return this.pagination.current_page;
            },
            pagesNumber: function(){
                if (!this.pagination.to) {
                    return [];
                }

                var from=this.pagination.current_page - this.offset;//pendiente(offset) TODO
                if (from<1) {
                    from=1;
                }

                var to=from+(this.offset*2);//TODO
                if (to>=this.pagination.last_page) {
                    to=this.pagination.last_page;
                }

                var pageArray=[];
                while(from<=to){
                    pageArray.push(from);
                    from++;
                }
                return pageArray;
            }

        },
        methods:{
            getPersonas:function(page){
                var urlPersona='personas?page='+page;
                axios.get(urlPersona).then(response=>{
                    this.texto='';
                    this.personas=response.data.personas.data;
                    this.pagination=response.data.pagination;
                });
            },
            deletePersonas:function(dni){
                var url = 'personas/'+dni;
                axios.delete(url).then(response=>{//eliminamos
                    this.getPersonas(); //listamos
                    toastr.success('Eliminado correctamente, DNI:'+dni);//manda mensaje
                });
            },
            createPersona: function(){
                var url='personas';  
                var persona=this.newPersona;     
                axios.post(url,persona).then(response=>{
                    this.getPersonas();
                    this.newPersona={PERS_varDNI: '', PERS_varApPaterno: '', PERS_varApMaterno: '', PERS_varNombres: ''},
                    this.errors=[];
                    $('#createPersona').modal('hide');
                    toastr.success('Nueva persona creada con exíto');
                }).catch(error=>{
                    this.errors=error.response.data
                });
            },
            editPersona: function(persona){
                this.fillPersona.PERS_varDNI=persona.PERS_varDNI;
                this.fillPersona.PERS_varApPaterno=persona.PERS_varApPaterno;
                this.fillPersona.PERS_varApMaterno=persona.PERS_varApMaterno;
                this.fillPersona.PERS_varNombres=persona.PERS_varNombres;
                this.errors=[];
                $('#editPersona').modal('show');            
            },
            updatePersona: function(id){
                var url='personas/'+id;
                axios.put(url, this.fillPersona).then(response=>{
                    this.getPersonas();
                    this.fillPersona={PERS_varDNI: '', PERS_varApPaterno: '', PERS_varApMaterno: '', PERS_varNombres: ''};
                    this.errors=[];
                    $('#editPersona').modal('hide');            
                    toastr.success('Actualización de datos exitosa');
                }).catch(error=>{
                    this.errors=error.response.data
                });
            },
            changePage: function(page){            
                this.pagination.current_page = page;
                this.getPersonas(page);            
            },
            findPersona: function(text){
                var url='buscador/'+text;
                axios.get(url).then(response=>{
                    this.personas=response.data.personas.data,
                    this.pagination=response.data.pagination
                });            
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

Lo que necesito es que cuando llame a la función `editPersona()` se abra un modal:

```
$('#editPersona').modal('show');
```

Antes usaba esto por que definía la vista en `views` y solo ponía:

```
@include('persona.createpersona')
@include('persona.editPersona')
```

Y podía llamarlo, ahora que lo volví componente, no sé cómo debo llamarlo, ya que debo enviar al modal datos en `fillPersona` y realizar los cambios con eso. En algunos casos vi que crean otro componente para el modal; si es así, ¿cómo le paso los datos de un componente a otro?

Comment: No está de mas usar signos de puntuación y tildes más seguido ;)

Comment: *En algunos casos vi que crean otro componente para el modal; si es así, ¿cómo le paso los datos de un componente a otro?*. Por atributo: `<modal-editar :data="tuvariableconlosdatos"></modal-editar>`.

Comment: Y esta todo explicado en el manual de vue: https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html

Comment: dentro del manual de vue https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#comp-ref-b-table
busca el ejemplo Complete example, y analizalo, aquí te explica muy bien